# How to set newest first in the view of content created

Tags: views

How to set **newest first** in view of content created. So far I have created a view for **content type** and now it's displaying created new content on last page but I want to set in first page. Can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: its simple change sorting order in view

Comment: @Adi: where exactly, and what to change, i couldn't find here

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/1578406 check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under *Sort Criteria* section, add field *Content: post date* and set it's configuration as *descending* as shown in image below.

[image]

Comment: where is sort criteria section? i could not find it, please check the screen shot i have attached

Comment: see below the *filter criteria* section.

Comment: look at this screenshot http://prntscr.com/8tkyjr

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'title' in field list is ambiguous ......error showing

Comment: what have you done before getting this error?

Comment: @ i clicked on add and added the fields and selected desc and apply.